# Должны ли закрытые вопросы оставаться видимыми?

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов

Обратил внимание вот на какой момент. В новых плашках на закрытие пишется, что вопрос закрыт и скрыт от всех:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот эта фраза меня сильно смущает:

> (Доступно для просмотра автору сообщения и участникам с правом
>   голосования за закрытие/переоткрытие вопросов)

Правильно ли я понимаю, что закрытые вопросы должны скрываться из ленты? У меня впечатление, что вопросы остаются на месте и плашка неверно информирует. Нет возможности проверить на залогиненном участнике без права закрытия/переотрытия -- но я проверил в приватной вкладке, оказалось: незалогиненные пользователи видят вопрос как по прямой ссылке (ну, почему и нет), так и в ленте по метке (прошло уже более 15 минут, так что дело не в "закешировалось).

Как это трактовать? На мой взгляд это либо "должно скрываться, но не скрывается", либо "не должно скрываться, текст информирует некорректно".

Comment: "Доступно для просмотра автору сообщения и участникам с правом голосования за закрытие/переоткрытие вопросов". Это не про сам вопрос, а про текст уведомления. Читать как "Этот информационный тест доступен только автору и бла-бла-бла...".

Comment: В принципе, дельное замечание. Можно перевод подправить.

Answer (score 7):

Нет, речь не о вопросе, а о списке участников, закрывших вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Вот англоязычный текст:

[image: closenotice]

Перевод почти дословный. Если он непонятен, можно его дополнить, но вопрос, как именно дополнить? Если заменить на "**Данный текст** доступен для просмотра ...", то кому-то все равно может быть непонятно, какая именно часть текста ограничена к просмотру, весь блок "Закрыт" или только его часть под линией? (На деле правильный ответ второй.) Если же начинать расписывать еще подробнее, текст станет слишком громоздким для того, что по сути должно быть второстепенной информацией. Если менять, нужно придумать компактный текст, который правильно отразит суть вещей. Или оставить все как есть, и дополнить справку по закрытию подробной информацией о том, что кому отображается?

Answer (score 1):

Надо убрать вообще это примечание. Зачем оно нужно?

Comment: Вот как ни странно, но это действительно ТОЖЕ ответ на вопрос. Я смотрел и так и так -- и думал, что там вообще весь текст лишний, особенно если сравнивать что и как показывается разным людям. Да, это на метамету надо писать, но вообще смысл такой, что и без этого сообщения весьма логично всё.

Comment: @AK, ну именно в поле для ответа я это и вписал. И сделал это потому что считаю это лучшим решением поставленного вопроса. На метумет, наверное, не обязательно это, мы ведь можем пустую строку в качестве перевода выставить?

Comment: @АндрейNOP конкретно в этом случае можем.

Comment: Это что-то типа "не рассказывайте всем подряд, что видели список закрывших" - никуда от этого не избавишься.